# media querys navegador edge

Tags: css, mediaqueries

Necesito colocar medias query solo para navegador edge

> medida mínima 400px  máxima 600px

¿Como seria?

tengo esto, necesito que funcione solo en navegador edge

```
@media screen and (max-width:400px) and (max-height:600px) {
   …
}
```

Comment: antes era [posible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32202953/4987172) pero ya no hay soporte para este tipo de casos

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto, pero Microsoft está trabajando para eliminar todos los prefijos -ms y así adaptarse a los estándares, por lo que si sigue funcionando este "truquillo" en algún momento dejará de hacerlo.

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) { 
    @media screen and (max-width:400px) and (max-height:600px) {
        ....
    }
}
```